# Is kill(pid, 0) guaranteed to return 0 if a process exists?

Tags: c++, centos, race-condition, pid

I am on Centos 4 and am using kill(pid, 0) in my C++ program to check whether there is presently a process running with the given pid. I am beginning to suspect that there is a race condition whereby shortly after a process has started, there is a small window of time wherein the kill(pid, 0) does not return zero even though there is actually a process running.

Is this a known issue?  Will kill() ever return non-zero when a pid actually exists but has just been started?  If kill() is not a reliable to test for existence, is there a better way to perform this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kill(pid, 0)` will only return 0 if the process exists and you would be able to send it a signal. If the process isn't running as you (and you aren't root), then the call will fail with -EPERM.

Comment: It also return ESRCH if no such pid.

Comment: This is unreliable if you're running as root. Since it will only fail with -EPERM indicating permission denied.

Comment: To be more precise, you need to either have the CAP_KILL capability in the user namespace of the target process (note: root has this capability, obviously) or the real or effective user ID of the sending process must equal the real or saved set-user-ID of the target process.